# How to refer to the local module in Python?

Tags: python, import, module, package

Let's say we have a module `m`:

```
var = None

def get_var():
    return var

def set_var(v):
    var = v
```

This will not work as expected, because `set_var()` will not store `v` in the module-wide `var`. It will create a local variable `var` instead.

So I need a way of referring the module `m` from within `set_var()`, which itself is a member of module `m`. How should I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [Jeffrey Aylesworth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832626/how-to-refer-to-the-local-module-in-python/1832635#1832635) shows, you don't actually need a reference to the local module to achieve the OP's aim. The `global` keyword can achieve this aim.

However for the sake of answering the OP title, *How to refer to the local module in Python?*:

```
import sys

var = None

def set_var(v):
    sys.modules[__name__].var = v

def get_var():
    return var
```

Answer (score 10):

```
def set_var(v):
    global var
    var = v
```

The global keyword will allow you to change global variables from within in a function.

Answer (score 3):

As a follow up to Jeffrey's answer, I would like to add that, in Python 3, you can more generally access a variable from the closest enclosing scope:

```
def set_local_var():

    var = None

    def set_var(v):
        nonlocal var  
        var = v

    return (var, set_var)

# Test:
(my_var, my_set) = set_local_var()
print my_var  # None
my_set(3)
print my_var  # Should now be 3
```

(Caveat: I have not tested this, as I don't have Python 3.)